# What is the quickest way to create a scatter plot per row in a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table with a list of customer spending per month. I want to create a scatter chart for each customer (row) to show the trend over time.

Currently I can only see that I can do it one-by-one. Is there a quicker way?

[image]

Comment: Could you please give a sample to show your data. Generally, you may create a chart series for each customer. Or you can try to record a macro to create a chart for one row.

Comment: Added the image to the original post. Sample of 5 customers but i have over 700 in total. One graph for all customers is too messy so i want one scatter plot per customer to visualise their trend.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am assuming you only want to check one client at a time.

You data is in a table like so:

[image]

Create a chart from a table built like this:

[image]

The formula to use in cell `B9` is:

```
=INDEX(B$2:B$5,MATCH($A9,$A$2:$A$5,0))
```

You can copy/paste it in columns `C, D`, etc.

In Cell `A9`, use a drop down of the list of companies:

[image]

Create a chart with `A8:F9` as source data

[image]

As you change the company name in `A9`, the chart will change to give you the appropriate data.

This could also be done for multiple companies at a time by adding rows as needed

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I do want one for each account so i can have a quick overview of a bunch of customers at a time, but this will do for now.

Side note, my Y Axis reads 1 2 3 4 5 etc rather than Jan Feb Mar Apr etc. Any idea why that is?

Comment: check to see if the headers are dates or text? also check the format of the axis labels

Comment: It was custom. Changed it to text, no joy. Changed it to short date, no joy.

Comment: Figured it out, Scatter Plots don't allow it. Had to change it to a line graph.